# What is the Google Sheets MIME Type?? (Drive API V3)

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google's Drive API V3 to make a Google Sheets file that I can then edit later. But I cannot for the life of me figure out what the actual mime type is to make such a sheet.

Further up in my code I renamed the using statement:

```
using GoogleFile = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;
```

So that it was easier to use. Then later in my code I am trying to construct an empty sheets file, but what is the mime-type??

```
GoogleFile fileMetaData = new GoogleFile()
{
    Name = "Project plan",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk"
};
```

Is all I got from looking at the Google API Site. I cannot find the one for Sheets. Is there some other way to use to make Sheets with that I just cannot find?

Comment: May this will help..https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types

Comment: @MannanBahelim Thank you! I searched so much, and could not find it T_T

Comment: Literally first result on "google sheets mime type".

Comment: @JuanFerrer My first results keeps directing me to the Javascript API and the example from above.